# How to catch upload failure transient errors in Azure blob storage?

Tags: typescript, azure, error-handling, transactions, azure-blob-storage

I have below working code of uploading files to Azure blob storage from the front end typescipt code.
I have to catch the errors related to upload failing scenarios, due to network or any other issues. How can we catch those errors on front end?
Suppose if I'm uploading a file size of 1GB, in middle of upload if there is any network issue, then once network available, will it resume or upload will start again from start?

```
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`,credentials);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
 const fileName = path.basename(localFilePath);
 const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("folder1/"+fileName);
 //const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
 const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
  blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to catch the errors related to upload failing scenarios, due to
> network or any other issues. How can we catch those errors on front
> end?

You could simply wrap your code in try/catch block. Whenever an error occurs from the storage side, an error object will be returned. That error object will contain a property called `statusCode`. You can check the status code to determine if the operation should be retried or not. For example, if the status code >= 400 and less than 500 then the operation should not be retried. Any status code >= 500 can be retried.

> Suppose if I'm uploading a file size of 1GB, in middle of upload if
> there is any network issue, then once network available, will it
> resume or upload will start again from start?

SDK will not resume the failed upload. It will start again from start. It would be your application's responsibility to maintain the upload state.